# ReferenceError when calling function

Tags: javascript

I am getting a reference error while I try to call a object function, and that object function is calling another function.

For example:

I have a function to return an object;

```
function krPano(){
    return document.getElementById("krObj");
}
```

Now I have a object literal that contains some helper functions that I want to use. For example:

```
var contextMenuInfo = {

        getContextMenuCount : function(){
            return KrPano().get("contextmenu").item.count;
        }
}
```

So in getContextMenuCount func I am using `KrPano()` to get the object.

Now again there is another function where I call the `getContextMenuCount` function.

```
function showDifferentContextMenu(){

    console.log(contextMenuInfo.getContextMenuCount());

}
```

When I execute this function, I get reference error saying `can't find variable KrPano.`

Comment: Your function is declared as `krPano()` and you're calling it as `KrPano()`. Are you sure this typo isn't happening in your code? Function and variable names are case sensitive in javascript.

Comment: i am sure there is no typo in calling the fnc krPano()

Comment: Um, are you really sure? lol

Comment: i am assuming that KrPano() calling inside the contextMenuInfo is doing something wrong?

Comment: The case `K` vs `k`

Comment: I'm saying that because it is what the error is pointing to.

Comment: oh HAHA, i din't see that coming

Comment: damn, i wasted time not trying to debug properly : 3

Comment: thanks guys, sorry for the trouble.@DontVoteMeDown , @epascarello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is defined as `krPano` when you're calling it as `KrPano`.

Do this instead (lowercase `k`):

```
return KrPano().get("contextmenu").item.count;
```

JavaScript is **case-sensitive**.